# Is it ok to use label without an input field?

Tags: html, css, forms

I need to add some info in my form that is not related to the input fields.

Can I use `<label>` without having an input field because I want to maintain a consistent look with the rest of the form's text? Or should I use another method?

Comment: You could use label without having an input. Depending on what should go in the label you could consider using a different html tag and style it with a class.

Comment: I personally wouldnt bother with it. Just create a `.label` class where you define your styles and use that class on `<p>` elements. The HTML Label Tag has several different functionalities built into it, especially for people using assistive technology like screen readers.

Comment: @MikkelDalby Thank you. But I wonder what other tag/style can I use?

Comment: A `<label>` is typically "A caption for an item" - notice I did not say "input" - and used a generic "item" term here so "item" can perhaps be other elements.  Alternatly you could use CSS to style say a `span` the same as your `label`, they are just tags

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss But a <label> behaves differently than a normal content tag in perspective of assistive technology..

Comment: @mewiben39 which tag to use i think depends on what type of content it has to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use label I think, but I don't suggest it. Use a span or a h(x) tag and add that tag to your css like :

```
label, span {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I decided to just create a new span class and copy the label's properties over. Crude but it works.

Comment: Can't you do it as I wrote with your classes using comma? Then there will be no duplicates of that code.

Comment: I'm using Gravity Form for WordPress so the `<label>` has a class called `gfield_label` but when I use it in a div, it doesn't look like the style of the labels.

Comment: Maybe because the label tag has default stylings too(for example: font-size, font-weight), try to look it up and expand that class of yours with those.